# onDataChanged() doesnt gets called when sending a specific byteArray in PutDataMapRequest

Tags: android, arrays, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I sending datas from **mobile to wear**, sometimes i will get the datas on Wear but sometimes **onDataChanged()** doesnt gets called when sending a specific **byteArray**(convert image into byte array) in PutDataMapRequest.Any clue

Comment: `onDataChanged` doesn't get invoked if the content doesn't change. Have a look to my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631002/cannot-send-an-asset-to-an-android-wear-device/28747495#28747495). It is not the best approach of the world, but it is the only way I found to force `onDataChanged` to get called

Comment: Yes. This is done to avoid unnecessary data transfer over bluetooth (which is slow and costs battery life). Its more like 304 status code of the http.